# Can I use Ubuntu's Azure AD login packages with an HTTP proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, azure-ad-msal, msal

I have an Ubuntu server and would like to use our Azure AD to authenticate our users with the [aad-auth](https://github.com/ubuntu/aad-auth) packages. However, I get timeouts. From an issue in Ubuntu's repository [it turns out](https://github.com/ubuntu/aad-auth/issues/220#issuecomment-1541605333) that this is probably due to Microsoft's Go library not supporting HTTP proxies.

The reason I think this is correct is that I also get timeouts when I use the `curl` command line tool making a request to https://login.microsoftonline.com. However when I set the `https_proxy` environment variable correctly I instantly get a response with `curl`. In syslog debug logging I see the error message that a request to https://login.microsoftonline.com timed out for PAM, too:

```
Get "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT ID REDACTED}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration": context deadline exceeded
```

This error message leads me to believe I am correctly configuring the Ubuntu AAD packages.

I have tried setting the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables in `/etc/environment` which helps for `curl` but not for PAM apparently. I am not sure what else to try as from a glance at the net/http Go documentation it looks like the devs at Microsoft need to build in HTTP proxy support in the Go library manually.

Indeed, in [comm.go](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/blob/main/apps/internal/oauth/ops/internal/comm/comm.go) which is where it seems all requests are made, I can't see any support for HTTP proxies.

I would like to know if there is any workaround for this that I can use, or if not, if it's on the roadmap or not: the devs say on GitHub that they are active in the msal tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a workaround for this issue at the moment. It is unclear if HTTP proxy support is on the roadmap for Microsoft's Go library.

Comment: No I actually kind of figured as much. The README on GitHub says the `msal` label is the best way to reach the devs and there was no question on this specific topic yet, so I thought I'd give it a shot.